# jquery/javascript: Capture submit event from form in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have a web page with an iframe which contains a form. I want to set a value in a hidden field when the form has been submitted. How can I trigger an event in the main page when the form is submitted?

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>TEST IFRAME UPLOAD</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     // Pseudo code for what I want to do
     // (this of course doesn't work because target is inside iframe:
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#file_upload_form").submit(function() {
           $("input[name='fileuploaded']").val(1);
           return true;
        });
     });
     </script>
  </head>

  <body>

     <form id="mainform" action="processform" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="fileuploaded" value="">
        <!-- more form fields here -->
     </form>

     <iframe id="upload-iframe">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file_upload_form" action="processfileupload" method="post">
           Select an image to upload:<br/>
           <input type="file" name="file">
           <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
     </iframe>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#upload-iframe').load(function() {
  $(this).contents().find('#file_upload_form').submit(function() { 
       $("input[name='fileuploaded']").val("some value"); // updated
      return true; //return false prevents submit
  });
});
```

Refered from [How can i bind an event to an element inside a local iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934541/how-can-i-bind-an-event-to-an-element-inside-a-local-iframe)

Can be possible duplicate of [Selecting a form which is in an iframe using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953436/selecting-a-form-which-is-in-an-iframe-using-jquery)

Comment: That doesnt work for me, input field does not get updated. I've moved the iframe contents into a seperate file the way I've shown it in my example is incorrect, so inside body tags now contains:

      <form id="mainform" action="processform" method="post">
         fileuploaded: <input type="text" name="fileuploaded" value="">
         <!-- more form fields here -->
      </form>
   
      <iframe id="upload-iframe" src="test.html"></iframe>

Comment: I'm guessing the problem with this solution is that $("input[name='fileuploaded']").val() = "1"; is acting within the context of the iframed document and not the parent document?

Comment: Your solution works great, Thanks! The problem was the val assignment issue that I introduced in my pseudo code and you updated in your solution.